# Can you say something like this in English?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, offensive-language

I am trying to translate from Russian a phrase that uses obscene vocabulary. I want it to be translated literally, only replacing unacceptable obscene words with more acceptable ones. The problem with the phrase is that all words it uses have the same obscene root.

The original Russian phrase:

> На**хуя** до**хуя** на**хуя**чили?! Рас**хуя**чивайте на**хуй**!

Translation:

> Why did you load so much? Unload it totally!

I wonder whether one can do the same in English, that is to say something like

> For what dick have you dicked it up to a dick? Undick this for dick!

or

> For what penis have you penised it up to a penis? Unpenis this for
>   penis!

Can it be understandable?

Comment: How about telling us what you are trying to say, rather than trying to just translate? You English phrases make no sense.

Comment: http://www.translatorscafe.com/tcterms/RU/thQuestion.aspx?id=42225

Comment: As a non-native speaker, I honestly don't have any idea what those sentences are trying to convey.... but perhaps if you change it to F-word, probably I can get the feeling of the speaker (e.g. very angry/upset). The problem with your current word selection is, both of them are nouns, which is not usually used as interjection. **Edit**: more-or-less already explained on above link.

Comment: I assume the bottom two translations are fairly literal word-for-word ones, and the tame translation at the top conveys the meaning but none of the invective feeling and word-root reuse. Anixx, you may want to edit the question to make that clear.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps something like:

> Shit! Why have you put such a shitload of this shit on! Unload all of this shit, now!

Comment: If it doesn't change the meaning too much, you could also say 'dump' instead of 'unload', which ties in with the scatological theme ('taking a dump' = defecating), but it implies throwing away what was loaded rather than just unloading it. You could say 'dump [it] back where it came from', but that is too awkward and loses its impact.

Comment: I have been pointed out to "Whaddafuck's this fuckload for? Un-fucking-load!" in the links above.

Comment: @Anixx- Yeah, but the Un-fucking-load doesn't really flow well.  And "Whadda" also doesn't work in my opinion because it drips with vehemence more when it's clearly enunciated.  "I'd go for: "What the fuck is all this shit? Get it the fuck outta here."  (And for some reason the *outta* is now correct rather than "out of"-  go figure.)

Comment: And of course if you are trying to replace obscene words with more palatable ones: "Uhm, what is all this stuff here?  Please remove it.  Now!"